# Introducing new member function to an outer class of a reusable header leading to failure in loading components which utilizes it

Tags: memory, visual-c++, dll, inner-classes, outer-classes

I have a reusable header which is consumed by multiple components. I introduced a member function and a member variable to the outer class and called it from one component. The implementation of the function was done in the .cpp of the reusable header. It was built successfully but while performing the workflow and opening the component, it could not get loaded and threw an error. The other components consuming the reusable header also couldn't get loaded.

To resolve it... In the header file, I introduced an inner class and created the member variable and member function to the inner class. I created the object of the inner class as a member of the outer class. Now everything is working fine. All the components using the header are properly loading.

Can anyone  please tell what could have gone wrong when the member variable and function was introduced for the outer class and how did it get resolved by using the inner class? 
I just know that by introducing the member variable to the outer class could have increased the dll size which might not be getting consumed properly. But, how did it get rectified by using inner class. 
Is the memory allocation playing a role here or, is it due to some other reason?

Below is the sample code from the reusable header that (1) didn't work and (2) did work:

(1)

```
class AFX_EXT_CLASS Class1
{
public:
   Class1()   {var = 8;};
   void Func1(int local);
   int var;
};
```

Note: Func1() gets called from multiple components other than the one it has been implemented into.

(2)

```
class AFX_EXT_CLASS Class1
{
public:
    Class1();

    class InnerClass
    {
    public:
        InnerClass(): var(8) {}

        void Func1(int local, Class1::InnerClass* objInnerClass)
        {
            objInnerClass->var = local;
        }

        int var;    
    };

public:
    Class1::InnerClass objMainInnerClass;
//This object is used to call Func1() from the components using the reusable header.
};
```

Comment: One possible difference: in the working example, `Func1` is defined inline in the header. In the non-working example, it is not defined. Are you sure you have actually provided the definition for it, and rebuilt the DLL with the new code?

Comment: Yes...the implementation of ```Func1``` has been done in cpp file for the header and the dll was rebuilt.

Comment: What error it throwing? Memory violation? and how component share between other? reusable component place in dll and share accross exe or in same project?

Comment: The error just says unable to load the component. The reusable header is an include file. This include is consumed by various dlls of the same exe.